# Want to add 400 panorama items dynamically

Tags: wpf, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7, panorama-control

I need to add nearly 400 images.I want to dispaly single image for each panorama item. If i add more than 25 images to the panorama item, the page hangs and stack error occurs. whats the solution for this...

Answer (score 1):

Panorama is the wrong control for this. The panorama is written so that every single item is loaded into memory - so loading 400 will result in out-of-memory and hanging type issues. If you really want to use Panorama then you could use the SelectionChanged event to control which panorama items actually contain content, but really I think this might not work even then...

Pivot would be a better choice - that just loads the current, previous and next at any one time. As with Panorama, it might also be useful to use SelectionChanged in your Pivot too - To that might help with loading times if nothing else.

Stuart

Comment: Can we do like this in panorama that load only 20 images first and when the user reached the 20th image then the first 19 images will go to the buffer or cache and next 20 images will loaded for view. is it possible?

Comment: only by coding it yourself using SelectionChanged event. I highly recommend you use the Pivot.